# How to stop EntityFramework migrations from creating my schema automatically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

All right, I'm using EntityFramework migrations, and they work fine, but when I run my application, (Web API) and the first time the context is used, the schema is created automatically for me. **I DO NOT want that**. I'd like to see an exception specifying that the tables do not exist or something like that.

In my configuration class I have something like this:

```
this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
```

I thought that was going to be enough but EntityFramework keeps re-creating my database schema.

Since I'm using a Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery process I want to use EF migrations to create the scripts for me and just check in my scripts and the scripts will be executed against the database for me (I already created that process)

*So how can stop EntityFramework migrations for trying to create my database schema automatically when the application runs (when the context is accessed the first time in the AppDomain)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unset the database initializer for your context.

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```